# JsonModel cannot convert an array in json to jsonmodel inherited class

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3, jsonmodel

I have modeled my api result as following:

```
#import "PTPDestination.h"
@interface PTPIndex : PTPBaseEntity
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber * citiesCount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber * hotelsCount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<PTPDestination *> * top_destinations;
@end
```

I also modeled PTPDestination like this:

```
@interface PTPDestination : PTPBaseEntity
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSNumber * id;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSNumber * min_price;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSNumber * max_discount;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString * title;
@end
```

And I call my api with AFNetworking like this:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager * manager = [self createAPISessionManager];
[manager GET:[self createServiceUrlWithMethod:@"someURL"] parameters:nil progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {
} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSError * error = nil;
    PTPIndex * index = [[PTPIndex alloc] initWithDictionary:responseObject error:&error];
    if (error) {
        callback (nil, [PTPApiCenteralizedErrorHandler getErrorFromApiError:error task:task responseObject:responseObject]);
        return;
    }
    callback (index, nil);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    callback (nil, [PTPApiCenteralizedErrorHandler getErrorFromApiError:error task:task]);
}];
```

The problem is with array of destinations. I don't know why the array is not converted to PTPDestination object and it remains as an array of NSDictionaries.

Why this happens and how can I have an array of my custom class?

Comment: Do you have an example of the JSON payload coming back from your server?

Comment: @CraigOtis I call this url ==> www.pintapin.com/service/index/mobile

Comment: What does `PTPBaseEntity` look like? Does it also extend `JSONModel`?

Comment: @CraigOtis Yes exactly. It extends JSONModel class.

Answer (score 0):

No, JSON Model Also Converted the Array to JSONObject, if you want to access the PTPDestination class properties.

PTPIndex class

```
#import "JSONModel.h"
@interface PTPIndex : JSONModel
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber * citiesCount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber * hotelsCount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<PTPDestination *> * top_destinations;
@end
```

PPTPDestination class

```
#import "JSONModel.h"
@interface PTPDestination : JSONModel
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSNumber * id;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSNumber * min_price;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSNumber * max_discount;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString * title;
@end
```

NSDictionary "data" from the network Response

```
PTPIndex *ptpInd = [[PTPIndex alloc] initWithDictionary:data error:&error];
```

find the total number of PTPDestination and run in the loop.
You can access the object like this.

```
PTPDestination *ptpdest = [ptpInd PTPDestination[0]];
```